# How to find the number of values in a drop-down menu with Python (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, dropdown

I am using Python (Selenium). I would like to download the data by looping the drop-down menu in the red circle. I can select the 4th one in the drop-down menu by

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="criteriaContainer"]/div[3]/div/select[1]/option[4]""").click()
```

But I wonder how I can find the total number of elements in the drop-down menu so that I can do an automatic loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this structure:

[image]

You'll notice that you can use the `xpath` indicator like this: 
`'//option[@value="1"]'` , where you'll need to change the value `1` to loop from 0 to a specific max value.

IMO, you have 2 approaches:

1. find a way to get the max value number of these option tags and iterate through them
2. create a `range` that goes `from 0 to 1.000`, for example, and use a `try/except` clause; if the selector exists, then do something, else, `break` the loop.

Example:

First approach:

```
for i in range(max_value_of_options):
    do_something()
```

Second approach:

```
for i in range(1000):
    try:
        do_something()
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like:

```
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="criteriaContainer"]/div[3]/div/select[1]""")
options = [x for x in select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")]
# len(options) will give you the number of how many options are in select box
```